# How to pass string to client and use RegEx to decide what action to take?

Tags: java, regex, client-server

I need to pass a string from the server to the client.  The string starts with "P1, " followed by the name of a playing card.  I want to use a regular expression on the client side to check to see if it starts with "P1, " and if so then pull the card information from the rest of the string and display that card.  However, I cannot seem to get the regular expression to recognize the string passed in.

Server side:

```
for(int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    imagePath1 = players[i].getCard(0).getImagePath();
    imagePath2 = players[i].getCard(0).getImagePath();
    output.format("%s\n", "Pocket Cards");
    output.flush();
    output.format("%s\n", "P1, " + imagePath1);
    output.flush();
}
```

Client side:

```
public void run() {
    playerNumber = input.nextLine();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                lblIdField.setText("You are Player " + playerNumber + ".");
            }
        }
    );
    myTurn = (playerNumber.equals("Player 1"));
    while(true) {
        if(input.hasNextLine()) {
            processMessage(input.nextLine());
        }
    }
}

public void processMessage(String message) {
    if(message.equals("Pocket Cards")) {
        //displayPocketCards("resources/10C.png");
    }
    else if(message.matches("P1, [.]*")) {
        String[] split = message.split(", ");
        displayPocketCards("resources/10C.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: how exactly will a correct message look like?

Comment: I think you would be better served in the long run to switch to using XML or JSON or something else of the sort. If you decide to make things more complex, your method will not be able to cope.

Comment: A correct message will look like "P1, 10C" where 10C means 10 of clubs.  P1 stands for Player Card 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you'd like to match strings starting with P, followed by one or several numbers, a comma, a separator, then any other characters.

Following code will probably do the trick :

```
    ...
    else if(message.matches("^(P)(\\d)+(\\,)(\\s)(.)*")) {
        String[] split = message.split(", ");
        displayPocketCards("resources/10C.png");
    }
}
```

Furhter you could use matching blocks to get your player's id, and the played card ...

There are a number of regexp testing sites you can use to check your regexps, here is one http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

When you make a character class that contains `.` it is not interpreted as the 'anything' wildcard, it is interpreted literally as a period.  Your message does not fully match "`P1,` followed by zero or more ." so you don't enter that block.  If you just want "match anything zero or more times" that is just `.*` with no brackets.  Although it is generally wise to be a bit more specific than that!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the method `matches()` I suggest using `startsWith()`. So instead of the `message.matches("P1, [.]*"))` you can use `message.startsWith("P1")` .

To parse the card info, I suggest you use another comma (and whitespace) between the number and card-type. Then you can easily use the split function you have to call `Integer.parseInt(split[1])` for the number and `split[2]` for the type.